# Python Scipy Value Error ("failed to create cache...")

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, scipy, least-squares

new to coding, so forgive me if this is a simple fix, but I am unsure of how to go about trouble shooting the error my code is giving me.

The code is simple, I was simply told to fit a polynomial of degree n (n=0,1,2..5) by least squares to the given data y, and t.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import linalg
t=np.array([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])
y=np.array([1.0,2.7,5.8,6.6,7.5,9.9])
for i in range(0,6):
    Ni=i
    Ai=np.vander(t,Ni,increasing=True)
    b=y
    xi=scipy.linalg.lstsq(Ai,b)[0]
    print(xi)
```

This outputs the following error "ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)"

Comment: You should probably use `Ni + 1` in `vander` a degree 0 polynomial still has 1 coeff.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much @PaulPanzer :)!